# C "%d" format specifier

Tags: c, format-specifiers

The following code gives me the output as 'd':

```
void main()
{

  short int a=5;

   printf("%d"+1,a);

   getch();

}
```

How does `printf()` actually work?

Comment: http://kkmaterials.blogspot.in/2012/06/printf-function-questions-and-answer.html I think,the same question has been asked here . try to search your questions before asking here .
than posting the questions with same values as this site , does not mean you have done any homework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` does not "see" the format specifier because you are passing a pointer to `"%d"` plus one. This is equivalent to passing `"d"` by itself:

```
printf("d", a);
```

will print `d` and ignore `a`. This is not specific to `printf`, pointer arithmetic works like that with all `char` pointers, including pointers obtained from string literals (i.e. double-quoted sequences of characters).

Answer (score 3):

here is the problem `printf("%d"+1,a);` it wont display because there is only one format
 specifier and this ("%d"+1) generate error

it can be either `printf("%d+1",a);` or `printf("%d",a+1);`

Answer (score 1):

String literals such as "%d" are *array expressions*, and in most contexts an array expression will be converted to a pointer expression whose value is the address of the first element of the array:

```
Item        Address        00   01   02   03
-----       -------        --   --   --   --
"%d"        0xfffbec00     '%'  'd'   0   ??
```

The string literal "%d" starts at address 0xfffbec00 (for example).  By writing `"%d"+1`, you're adding 1 to the resulting pointer value (giving 0xfffbec01), so you're effectively passing the string literal "d" to `printf`.

Since the string "d" does not contain a format specifier, `printf` prints the string as-is.  The argument `a` is *evaluated* before being passed to `printf`, but is otherwise ignored.